# How to work correctly with backreferences in java regex?

Tags: java, regex, back

I have created simple demo to see how backreferences work. It is

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)([,=]+)\\2\\1");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("2==2 5,,,,5");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group();
        System.out.println("group=" + group);
    }
```

The output is :

```
group=2==2
group=5,,,,5
```

Can someone explain why `5,,,,5` is matched by backreference \\2 ?

Comment: `5,,,,5` is not matched by backreference `\\2`. Only `,,` part is since it is contend of group 2.

Comment: Thanks I didn't get such simple fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Matcher#group()` states

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

On your second loop, it returns the 2nd match in your string. That is

```
5,,,,5
```

where the `([0-9]+)` matches `5`, the `([,=]+)` matches `,,`, the `\\2` matches the `,,` and the `\\1` matches the `5`.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Okay. You might want to check out [this link](http://www.regex101.com) for a good tool to understand regexes.